# OpenModelica with Python (OMPython)

Tags: python, modelica, openmodelica

I am new to OpenModelica.

I have developed a system of 10 discretized equations (time and space) with 10 unknowns to describe the behavior of a phase change material storage [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBnIz.png). I coded them on Python. Would it be possible to transpose them to OpenModelica using OMPython? (in order to use the OpenModelica simulator/optimizer to solve this system). I can't find anything about this on the forums...

Eventually, I would like to create a storage module, including this system of equations to form a new module (component) on OpenModelica and to link it to other modules to make my system more complex.

Comment: Hey. Can you provide a minimal example of what you are trying to achieve? And do you mean the language Modelica or the tool OpenModelica for modelling and simulating in said language? In case it is a general Modelica language question you should also add the modelica tag.

Comment: Hello,
I added an image to explain what I want to model and gave the discredited equations (time and space).
I would like to use my Python code (which solves the equations in the figure with for loops to determine the x and y coordinates of the different matrices) directly on the OpenModelica software without having to rewrite it in the Modelica language.
Then, I would like to use the OpenModelica tool to simulate the system and then optimize it.

Comment: OMPython is only an interface to the OpenModelica compiler. So you still have to translate your model into a Modelica one to be able to simulate it.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will do it...